# how to make a batch archiving programm?

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, archive

i have made a bat file to backup my data, website logs, but that takes up a lot of storage. it is scheduled, using task scheduler to run every night.

i would like to make another program, that runs every week and archives(copies the most recent backup to another location) and then deletes all of the daily backups

i would like to end up with a folder (e:\archives\logs\backup-1,backup-7,.....) that has all the archived backups in and then another folder that only ever has the most recent weeks backups in it (e:\backups\logs\backup-1,backup-2,...........)

many thanks for those who reply!

Comment: your question is to ambigous to have a simple answer. Just some thoughts. I never ever. choose such Date Format. The only sensible order is yyyy MM dd. When you copy and delete afterwards it's a much better idea to move - no hassle when the process gets interrupted. There are a lot of Tools to use to zip, compress copy/move, Just use batch to glue them together.

Comment: Gotta agree with LotPings, the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard of YYYY-MM-DD exists for a reason.

Comment: i have already got it to name it with the date, i just want to have it copy one out and delete the rest every 7 days

Comment: this is the code that i use for the backup
`code` xcopy "c:\iis logs" "e:\iis logs backup\Backup-%date:/=-%"" /s /e /i /y `code`

Comment: use forfile command check this link for more information [More data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: @trebor97351 Do you know that each Windows since Windows XP has a backup utility which can be used to make entire machine backups as well as backups of specific data folders? Or for your task it would make sense to use a compression tool like 7-Zip or WinRAR to backup the logs with maximum compression each day and finally also weekly with a maximum number for the weekly backups. WinRAR has special switches for such backup operations.